# MapFragment manager error in sub class of app

Tags: java, android, google-maps-android-api-2

I am trying to make a class that deals with the various googleMap realated functions and tasks.

This includes setting up the map itself, handling markers etc.

My problem is... the code I have works fine if its all in the same file as my main activity, however the following does not work when I move it into a separate class.

**UPDATE**

```
public class Mapper extends Activity {

        GoogleMap googleMap;
    public Mapper(Context context) {

            this.context = context;

            getMap();
    }

        private void getMap() {

        googleMap = ((MapFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.googleMap)).getMap();

        }

    }
```

I get the following error:

http://puu.sh/4pLxT.png

I am really unsure as to why it works in the main class but not this one.

Any help would be amazing!

Comment: Please paste the code directly here. No pictures. Are you trying to call Activity methods from a class that it is not an Activity? How can this work?

Comment: Please paste the error as well. No pictures.

Comment: Its much easier and more convenient for us to help you if you post relevant code **and** logcat into the question so we don't have to flip back and forth. Also, why the constructor? Are you trying to instantiate this `Activity` from another???

Answer (score 0):

You are calling a method from the constructor even before `onCreate()`. Nothing is inflated at this point. I think you need to read about how `Activities` and `Fragments` [work](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html).